# Error : used for two different module paths

Tags: go, grpc

I am getting a error when I am trying to run  `go build` ,  Error is something like this :

```
go: golang.org/x/lint@v0.0.0-20201208152925-83fdc39ff7b5 used for
   two different module paths (github.com/golang/lint and golang.org/x/lint)
```

and my **go.mod** file is like

```
module gitlab.com/proj-ride/proj-src/services/event

go 1.14

require (
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.3
    github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.4 // indirect
    golang.org/dl v0.0.0-20210220033039-562909534da3 // indirect
    golang.org/x/lint v0.0.0-20201208152925-83fdc39ff7b5 // indirect
    golang.org/x/tools v0.1.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20200804184101-5ec99f83aff1 // indirect
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.25.0
)

replace github.com/golang/lint => golang.org/x/lint v0.0.0-20201208152925-83fdc39ff7b5
```

**EDIT**

```
In case if I don't use `replace github.com/golang/lint`
```

my go.sum file contain it like this

```
github.com/golang/lint v0.0.0-20180702182130-06c8688daad7 h1:2hRPrmiwPrp3fQX967rNJIhQPtiGXdlQWAxKbKw3VHA=
github.com/golang/lint v0.0.0-20180702182130-06c8688daad7/go.mod h1:tluoj9z5200jBnyusfRPU2LqT6J+DAorxEvtC7LHB+E=
github.com/golang/lint v0.0.0-20201208152925-83fdc39ff7b5/go.mod h1:3xt1FjdF8hUf6vQPIChWIBhFzV8gjjsPE/fR3IyQdNY=
```

how I can replace this with ?
`golang.org/x/lint`  as there are versions mentioned

Comment: golang.org/x/lint is the correct import path. Stop that replace nonsense and make sure to _only_ use the correct import path only.

Comment: Listen. I'm trying to help. You cannot import a package trough several import paths and `replace`ing is **not** going to help. Stop that, it is not leading anywhere. You **must** import that package solely through the one proper import path. If you do not want help: Do not ask.

Comment: @Volker  I checked in whole project but there is never used  of this  `github.com/golang/lint`   . still I am getting this error  `module declares its path as: golang.org/x/lint but was required as: github.com/golang/lint`   to bypass this error I used this `replace` thing which is suggested on `github golang issue`  now then tell how I can fix this error without `replace`  because there is nothing other then that ?

Comment: Look. Everything looks fishy here. Go 1.14 is no longer supported, you project uses to different protobuf implementations and somewhere in your code or a dependency github.com/golang/lint is imported which is wrong. You must find where github.com/golang/lint is imported. `go mod why` and `go mod graph` might be helpful.

Comment: @Volker I found usaged of   `github.com/golang/lint`  and updated my question can you please tell now how I can replace with  `golang.org/x/lint` as there are strange versions mentioned

Comment: 'go mod tidy' might help cleaning 'go.sum' (https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-tidy)

Comment: go.sum is not your problem. Just delete it.

Comment: @Volker deleted  now should I re build or what ? other then that  no existence of   `github.com/golang/lint`

Comment: Yes run go build.

Comment: @Volker    **Now giving this error**    `go get: github.com/golang/lint@v0.0.0-20201208152925-83fdc39ff7b5: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: golang.org/x/lint
                but was required as: github.com/golang/lint`

Comment: @ConstantinKonstantinidis  Now giving this error  ` go get: github.com/golang/lint@v0.0.0-20201208152925-83fdc39ff7b5: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: golang.org/x/lint
                but was required as: github.com/golang/lint`

Comment: Fatima, try clearing the mod cache and try again after that. Here: `go clean -modcache`

Comment: And why there is `google.golang.org/protobuf` as well as `github.com/golang/protobuf`?

Comment: @shmsr  It was old project some of the code depend on old `github.com/golang/protobuf`    . And Onward work is being done using latest one . I think

Comment: Again: You **must** get rid of **all** references to github.com/golang/lint. Direct ones and in any package you import. That is the **only** fix. If a package import github.com/golang/lint it is broken and you **cannot** and **must not** use it. and get rid of the multiple protobuf.

Comment: @Volker  how I can get idea which module is importing this old lint ? Is that being import by my `go.mod`  ?

Comment: go.mod doesn't import _anything_, it just records module versions. It is in your code or code you import with `import`. You have to _look_. Use `grep` and `go mod why`. Finding the problematic code is _work_. No shortcuts, sorry.

Comment: Excluding the version which should be upgraded might help. Instead of replace directive, use exclude golang.org/golang/lint

Comment: Fatima, did you try clearing the modcache?

Comment: @shmsr   now getting these kind of errors     `module google.golang.org/genproto@latest found (v0.0.0-20210226172003-ab064af71705), but does not contain package google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/asset/v1beta1
can't load package: package github.com/BurntSushi/xgb/examples: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/emumba/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!burnt!sushi/xgb@v0.0.0-20210121224620-deaf085860bc/examples`

Comment: @ConstantinKonstantinidis  thanks sir , `excluding` did the trick. now don't know either it will work always or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`go mod tidy` might be useful to clear unwanted dependencies.

In this case, the message reports that one dependency is required by separate modules:

```
go: golang.org/x/lint@v0.0.0-20201208152925-83fdc39ff7b5 used for
   two different module paths (github.com/golang/lint and golang.org/x/lint)
```

It is always better to upgrade to latest version as feasible.
When using replace, the path remains as explained in the [documentation](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace).

Excluding the older dependency might work if compatibility is preserved by the latest dependency. Directive spells like: `exclude github.com/golang/lint`