# Replacing Go dependency with fork: "... used for two different module paths"

Tags: go, dependency-management, go-modules, git-fork

I have a very large Go project that depends on [`github.com/golang/mock`](https://github.com/golang/mock). Unfortunately, this package is no longer maintained, and the developers have directed people to use the fork at [`go.uber.org/mock`](https://github.com/uber/mock). So I'd like to replace the `github.com/golang/mock` dependency with `go.uber.org/mock`.

As I understand it, this is exactly what go.mod's `replace` directive is for (allowing you to replace a dependency without having to change the import path in every single file). So, replacing this module with the fork should be as easy as adding the following line to my `go.mod`:

```
replace github.com/golang/mock => go.uber.org/mock v0.2.0
```

Unfortunately, this is causing errors when trying to run any `go` command:

```
$ go mod tidy
...
go: go.uber.org/mock@v0.2.0 used for two different module paths (github.com/golang/mock and go.uber.org/mock)
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

You can view the repo/commit [here](https://github.com/barrettj12/juju/commit/07e97bb5736043076430f366feff38a2d4dd5ba5) if necessary.

Comment: The go.mod `replace` directive isn't really meant for your use case; although, it can be used for it in some situations. Your problem is probably because a package you depend on has a dependency on the older code. The `replace` directive is not transitive -- it only applies to your code. Try `go mod why` to gain more insight.  Also, google `replace used for two different module paths` which will lead you to previous questions and answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66408901/error-used-for-two-different-module-paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the doc of the [replace directive](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace):

> Regardless of whether a replacement is specified with a local path or module path, if the replacement module has a go.mod file, its module directive must match the module path it replaces.

The `replace` directive can not be used here.

Since `go.uber.org/mock` is published with a different module path, I think you have to treat it as a totally different module than `github.com/golang/mock`.

Comment: Damn, so I have no choice but to replace the import path in every file of my repository?

Comment: I think so. It's easy to do a find and replace in an IDE.